# Best way to access server side method from client side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using webmethod and AjaxPro, to access server side method from client side .Is any other ways to access to server side method,better than these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery ajax method is very easy to use for these needs.

Please check more info here - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

And this one - http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Example:

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
 data: "{}",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(msg) {
// Do something interesting here.
}
});
```